# Button to populate image from array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, uiimage, uibutton

Hey guys i have an image view, with a popover controller. 
There is an array called detailitem which loads images into the image view. 
All i want is a button to load next image in array into the image view
how would i write this?
Here is my attempt it doesn't work?

```
-(IBAction) nextitem {
    NSString * imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[detailItem objectAtIndex:+1]];
    imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of which index in the array is currently begin displayed.

Add an imageIndex instance variable to your class and initialize it to 0

```
-(IBAction) nextitem {
    imageIndex++;
    if(imageIndex == [detailItem count]) imageIndex = 0; // don't overrun the end of the array
    NSString * imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[detailItem objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
    imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect

```
  [detailItem objectAtIndex:+1]
```

To do?  It will always pass 1 and get the 2nd element of the array.  If you want to loop through the array, you need to keep an index somewhere (in a property, for example) and increment it.